# Gradient one-form

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, differentiation, vector-fields

I am trying to understand what gradient one-form means actually. In the book that I'm following (A first course on General Relativity by Schutz) it's told that gradient is a one-form and it's association with the "gradient vector" is a one-to-one map through the metric tensor (Lorentz metric in the book). I am having trouble understanding what the components of the gradient one-form $ \tilde d \phi$ (of some scalar field $\phi$) $\{\frac {\partial \phi}{\partial x^\alpha}\}$ stand for. What meaning do these component values just by themselves hold at a point {$x^\alpha$}, given that the rate of change of $\phi$ depends on the direction we take. Is it the case that, only when $ \tilde d \phi$ is supplied with a "unit" vector it gets a physical meaning, "the rate of change of $\phi$ in that direction"?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/159313/2451

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your last sentence shows you're on the right track. A one form is a *linear functional* that maps vectors to real numbers. You give it a vector as an input, and, as you say, it returns the rate of change in the implied direction.

Let's say we have a path whose tangent at a point is defined by the vector $v^j\,\partial_j$ - the differential operator that operates on a smooth scalar field $\psi$ and returns the total derivative $\mathrm{D}_v\psi = v^j\,\partial_j\,\psi$. A one form $\mathrm{d}u$, being a linear, homogeneous functional of vectors, is defined wholly by its values at the basis vectors - *i.e.* by its values $u_1,\,u_2,\,\cdots$ at the basis tangent vectors $\partial_1,\,\partial_2,\,\cdots$ (in components, the latter are $(1,0,0,\cdots),\, (0,1,0,\cdots),\,\cdots$)

Well the gradient $\nabla\phi$ is just such a beast. Its value when we input the tangent vector $\partial_j$ with components $(0,0,,\cdots,1,\,\cdots)$ (with one "1" in the $j^{th}$ position), the value of the functional is $\partial\phi/\partial x^j$.

We simply sum up these basis values by superposition: take the inner product with the vector $(v^1,\,v^2,\,\cdots)$ to find the functional's value and your value is $v^j\,\partial\phi/\partial x^j$ - the total rate of change of $\phi$ in the direction implied by $\vec{v}$.

I also like Schutz's visualization of a one-form as a system of hyperplanes: the value being the rate at which a vector pierces the hyperplanes. The classic, prototypical one form is the wavenumber , where you imagine phase fronts. The rate at which a vector $\vec{r}$ pierces the phasefronts is $k(\vec{r})$; in optics we often loose sight of this and treat $k(\cdot)$ as a vector. If we want to reconcile this with the above, we understand that the wavenumber has meaning as an *inner product*, so the wavevector in optics, if we were calculating in curved space, is the wavenumber one-form *converted* to a vector by raising its index with the metric: the $\vec{k}$ we ken and love in optics is in fact the "sharpened" $\vec{k} = k()^\sharp$ (a shorthand for raising an index) so that $\vec{k}^\mu = g^{\mu\,\nu}\,k(\cdot)_\nu$. I think it would be enlightening for you to read and think about the [wavenumber in Minkowski spacetime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_vector#In_special_relativity).