# Line element 1-form in the metric tensor

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, calculus

It was pointed out that dual vectors of a manifold, and hence differential 1-forms, are not dependent on the metric ([Intuition behind dual vectors ('Bongs of a bell' does not help)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/452774/)). But doesn't the line element include both the metric and differential 1-forms?

$$ds^2 = (dx^1)^2 + (dx^2)^2.$$
Or,
$$ds^2 = g_{\mu\nu} dx^{\mu} dx^{\nu}.$$

Here, isn't $dx$ a differential 1-form? Also trying to synthesize good post here (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/483191/).

Comment: "The line element" is not a differential form.

Comment: I'm confused: what does the line element including the metric and 1-forms have to do with 1-forms depending on the metric?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The metric tensor $$\mathbb{g}~=~g_{\mu\nu}\mathrm{d}x^{\mu}\odot \mathrm{d}x^{\nu}$$ is a section in the symmetric tensor product $$T^{\ast}M\odot T^{\ast}M.$$ It has an interpretation as an *infinitesimal arclength square* via a generalization of the [Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem), which explains the common notation $ds^2$.

So $\mathrm{d}x^{\mu}$ is indeed a basis for covectors/1-forms, but $\mathbb{g}$ is *not* a 2-form, and [$ds$ is](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/483191/11127) *not* [a 1-form](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/456212/11127). For more details, see my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/323736/2451).